# sed + how to delete the second character "." from the line

Tags: linux, bash, sed

how to delete the second character "." from the line

what I have is this ( but its remove the first "." from output

```
uname -r | sed s'/\./ /'

2 6.18-164.2.1.el5PAE
```

while I need the following output

```
2.6 18-164.2.1.el5PAE
```

Comment: Please also show us the _input_. I can extrapolate from the output and assume that your input is `2.6.18-164.2.1.el5PAE` but including it would make the question clearer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply add N to the end of the command for it to match the Nth match, like this:

```
uname -r | sed 's/\./ /2'
```

What do you need it for though?

---

From the `info` page on `sed`:

> The `s' command can be followed by zero or more of the following
>   FLAGS:
>
> g
>
> ```
> Apply the replacement to _all_ matches to the REGEXP, not just the first.
> ```
>
> NUMBER
>
> ```
> Only replace the NUMBERth match of the REGEXP.
> ```

Comment: I need only the first number from uname -r ( 2.6 ) all other numbers are non relevant anyway thx on your good answer

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways to remove the second `.` from a line of a file (they will affect all lines of the file):

1. `sed`. You [already have](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159419/22222) what is probably the best way, but here's another:

   ```
   sed 's/\([^.]*\.[^.]*\)\./\1 /' file
   ```

   This will look for the longest stretch of non-`.` (`[^.]*`), then a `.` (`\.`), then the next stretch of non-`.` and finally a `.` (`\.`). The parentheses capture the patterns so we can refer to it as `\1`. Therefore, the command above will just delete the second `.` and replace it with a space.

   If you have GNU `sed` (default on Linux), you can simplify to:

   ```
   sed -r 's/([^.]*\.[^.]*)\./\1 /' file
   ```
2. Perl

   ```
   perl -pe 's/([^.]*\.[^.]*)\./\1 /' file
   ```

   or

   ```
   perl -F'\.' -ane 'print "$F[0].$F[1] ", join ".", @F[2..$#F]' file
   ```
3. `awk` (I'm sure there's a better way)

   ```
   awk -F. '{printf "%s.%s ",$1,$2; for(i=3;i<NF;i++){printf "%s.",$(i); }print $NF}' file
   ```